# How to set Speak field in the Azure bot's output activity?

Tags: azure, speech-recognition, direct-line-botframework

In the Cognitive-Services-Direct-Line-Speech-Client documentation, they have mentioned that "You'll only hear the bot's voice response if the Speak field in the bot's output activity was set." But from where we set the BOT's output activity speak field?

Please refer the link below.

[Direct Line speech client](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/Cognitive-Services-Direct-Line-Speech-Client/blob/master/README.md)

Answer (score 0):

You just need to add what you want to be spoken on your bot SendActivityAsync call. 
For Example: 
await stepContext.Context.SendActivityAsync("Hello", "Hello", cancellationToken: cancellationToken);
The second SendActivityAsync parameter is actually what the bot will be saying.